# What Mime Type should I use for BASIC code?

Tags: mime-types, basic

What is the mime type for BASIC code? I searched the interwebs but found nothing... maybe application/basic, or text/basic, or..? Visual Basic, or QBasic, any should do. I'm trying to get my ViewVC setup to do syntax highlighting for .bas files... at the moment I've set .bas as text/plain so no syntax highlighting occurs, but I'd rather have it if I can.

Comment: Have you tried vbscript style configuration? Or vb.net? Maybe this helps. I don't know if it's correct to call this "mime type", cause all of this is I think text/plain.

Comment: Officially, it's just `text/plain`. It's likely too much of a hassle to denote Apple BASIC vs. Microsoft QuickBASIC vs. C64 BASIC vs. Liberty Basic vs. Visual Basic in terms of media types; their syntax is varied enough to warrant completely different media types. Even the Google Prettify library only [supports a reasonable subset of BASIC code](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/src/lang-basic.js) and [VB](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/src/lang-vb.js) specifically. Maybe you can create your own highlighting? I've never used ViewVC, so I don't know.

Comment: I thing you got it: try to create your own style configuration. If ViewVC doesn't allow you, contact the devs! Every piece of soft can be upgraded by community needs and efforts like yours ;)

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you are trying to save in a other-program-readable format or in the qbasic format - at least in QB64.

If you are saving it readable for other programs, `text/plain` is correct.  Otherwise, it would be `application/octet-stream`.